# Узнать сколько дней в интервале дат

Tags: jquery

Добрый день! Есть два input. Туда человек вбивает две даты. Дату заезда и дату выезда. Как узнать сколько дней между этими датами. Например: Дата заезда 16.06.2016 дата выезда 22.06.2016. Кол-во дне 6. Реализовывать хочу на jquery.

Comment: нужно вычесть одну дату из другой и посчитать сколько результат в днях

Comment: Посмотрите, может, подойдет: http://jsfiddle.net/MebwN/49/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12003660/javascript-datediff может поможет, правда там на чистом js, но это же только плюс

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224834/get-difference-between-2-dates-in-javascript) ответ на ваш вопрос.

- Создать две переменные типа Date, передав обязательно даты как строку обернутую кавычками.
- Получить разницу между датами в миллисекундах.
- Применить деление, чтобы привести результат к дням.

```js
var date1 = new Date("7/13/2010");

var date2 = new Date("12/15/2010");

var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());

var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));

alert(diffDays);
```